# How to insert data from a spinner to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, insert, spinner

I am trying to add data from spinners and text to Firebase. My app is basically a survey where the user selects their answers through each spinner, enters text for one and selects values from a checkbox.

I do not know how to approach this.

I can already read from my database but I now need to add to it. My database is as follows:

**Firebase Data**

[image]

**My android**

[image]

The only code I have for each spinner so far is as follows;

```
//Spinner7
    spinner7=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
    ArrayAdapter adapter7=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.rating, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner7.setAdapter(adapter7);

    spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
String text = spinner7.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

then use your databaseReference

```
mTempDatabaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("interview).child("1);
mmTempDatabaseReference.child("interviewed").setValue(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the selected **itemID** and store the value in a **String** Variable

```
public static String departmentID;    

spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            departmentID = spinnerDepartment.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

and then set that value to database

```
   DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
   databaseReference.setValue(departmentID);
```